# How to call javascript or select dropdown value in OnChange event with multiple arguements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onchange

I am very new to this and I think I should not be mixing all of the things like client side and server side... but I can't think of any other option.

What I want is to accept dropdown selected value and write it back to DB using `onChange` function.

```
<div class="control-group" onChange="saveTasks('<?php echo $row["taskid"]; ?>', **this.selectedIndex** ,'vendorname')">
```

Problem is I am having PHP function too and `this.selectedIndex` as HTML function.

I have tried JS instead of `this.selectedIndex` as well (mentioned below):

```
<div class="control-group" onChange= "saveTasks('<?php echo $row["taskid"]; ?>', **myFunction()** ,'vendorname')">
```

but don't know what is right syntax.

Comment: You are trying to set `onchange` on `div` element. Well, you can't do this. Only on form input like `input`, `select` etc.

Comment: oh you are great! works deliciously!!!